# problem setting up MusicTeX

Tags: musixtex

I have huge trouble setting up MusixTeX with Texmaker. Apparently, there's a lack of documentation on how to install MusixTeX and also tutorials on how to use it. Can anyone help me with the setup?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: well, musicTeX or musixTeX? two different things

Comment: @musicman indeed, but (a) they have the same parentage, and (b) no-one (in their right mind) will use musictex now, surely?  (i did, once ... never again.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you mean MusiXTeX. Try to execute following example, Texmaker hopefully installs the needed package(s):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{music}\nostartrule
\instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
\setname1{Piano} % whose name is Piano
\setstaffs1{2} % with two staffs
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}% 4/4 meter chosen
\startextract % starting real score
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\ql l\sk\ql n\en
\bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{dgf}|\qlp i\en
\notes\tbu0\qb0g|\ibbl1j3\qb1j\tbl1\qb1k\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\zendextract % terminate excerpt
\end{music}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{music}\nostartrule
\instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
\setname1{Piano} % whose name is Piano
\setstaffs1{2} % with two staffs
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}% 4/4 meter chosen
\startextract % starting real score
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\ql l\sk\ql n\en
\bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{dgf}|\qlp i\en
\notes\tbu0\qb0g|\ibbl1j3\qb1j\tbl1\qb1k\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\zendextract % terminate excerpt
\end{music}
\end{lstlisting}

\bigskip

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\textbackslash ibu0f0 begins an upper beam, aligned on the f , reference number 0, slope 0\par
\textbackslash tbu0 terminates this beam before writing the second g by means of \textbackslash qb0g\par
\textbackslash qb.. indicates a note belonging to a beam.\par
\textbackslash sk sets a space between the two quarters in the right hand, so that the second one is aligned with the third eighth in the left hand.\par
\textbackslash qlp is a dotted quarter note.\par
\textbackslash ibbl1j3 begins a double beam, aligned on the C (j at this pitch) with slope 15 percent.\par

\end{document}
```

I took the example from the MusiXTeX manual (with a few changes)